# Missing encoding in POST request headers

Tags: html, forms, http, encoding

If I send a HTML page with UTF-8 encoding which contains a form, is it correct that the browser does not specify the encoding in the POST request header parameters?

I have tested it with the current version of Firefox 18 and Internet Explorer 9 (see below).

Based on the answer to [Why does POST not honor charset, but an AJAX request does? tomcat 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4392610/why-does-post-not-honor-charset-but-an-ajax-request-does-tomcat-6), setting the HTML page encoding 'will set the response encoding to UTF-8 and set the response header to UTF-8'.

In my tests, the response headers did not specify that the form values are encoded in UTF-8.

Is this as specified?

> ```
> Request: POST /demo/form.html HTTP/1.1
> Accept: text/html, application/xhtml+xml, */*
> Referer: http://127.0.0.1:8080/demo/form.html
> Accept-Language: de
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.0; Trident/5.0)
> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
> Host: 127.0.0.1:8080
> Content-Length: 29
> Connection: Keep-Alive
> Cache-Control: no-cache
> ```

Comment: may be this helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418944/how-to-force-browser-to-set-charset-in-content-type-http-header

Answer (score 1):

The application/x-www-form-urlencoded media type doesn't have a charset parameter, so the browser behavior is correct.